# How to get active listing IDs? GetMyeBaySelling returns no more than 25,000 items

Tags: ebay-api

So I want to get all listed items ID's for authenticated user.

To do this I use [Trading API GetMyeBaySelling method](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/reference/ebay/GetMyeBaySelling.html)

Example request:

```
[ActiveList] => Array
    (
        [Include] => true
        [Pagination] => Array
            (
                [EntriesPerPage] => 200
                [PageNumber] => 89
            )

        [Sort] => StartTime
    )
```

It works well until I hit magic page 125. Every page after 126, 127, 128, ... returns me 125th page.

So I can get only 25,000 listings. I don't see it mentioned anywhere in documentation.

[I also found other people have same/similar issue](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/2848/getmyebayselling-call-return-wrong-number-of-items.html)

Is there any other option to get selelr listing IDs?

**Edit:** [I also asked a question on ebaydev forums](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/8223/getsellerlist-returns-only-125-pages-25000-items.html)

I tried to load 125 pages sorted by time ASC, then load another 125 sorted by time DESC but it doesnt work. Also I am getting this error

```
[Errors] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ShortMessage] => Data is truncated.
        [LongMessage] => Partial data or invalid summary data is returned due to system limit. Please narrow your requested data and try again.
        [ErrorCode] => 21366
        [SeverityCode] => Warning
        [ErrorClassification] => RequestError
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer already.

[ActiveInventoryReport call](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/merchant-data/CallRef/ActiveInventoryReport.html) from Large Merchant Services is perfect for my needs